# Weird output packing newline character into string C

Tags: c

Sorry for the weird wording didn't really know how to describe the issue, anyway here is my code.

```
while(1){
 if ((ch = getch()) == 105) {
   break;
   //ToDO
 }else{
   buffer[i] = ch;
   i++;
   while ((ch = getch()) != 10){
     buffer[i] = ch;
     i++;
   }
   buffer[i] = '\n';
   i++;
   write(1,buffer, i);
   i = 0;
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if the first character of your input is an 'i' the program will do other things, if not then it will build a string of your input and print it out.

The output however jumps to a newline then pads out to the end of the previous string, I'm new to ncurses so I don't really know what's going on.

```
hello
     hello
          itsa nice day woo
                           whats up
```

Comment: What would happen if you insert the new line in a following step?  Right now it looks like you're asking it to place the new line before the write at the end.  Also, could the '1' flag to the bigger have anything to do with the tab?

Comment: What does ncurses have to do with it?  I don't see anything related to ncurses in the code you presented.

Comment: What OS is this running on?

Comment: Is there some special reason you are using `write()` instead of `puts()`, `fputs()`, or even `printf()`?  These others would require null termination in the buffer, but that's no particular difficulty.

Comment: `\n` is interpreted different in different terminals. If your terminal just interpret it as "new line" and not "new line + carriage return" then this looks plausible.

Comment: There are 2 ways to solve this: Easy way is to output a carriage return (13 == '\r') when you encounter a line feed (10 == '\n') as line feed only moves down, carriage return moves the cursor left where you might expect... A harder but better way is to check if you have a terminal, and set the ONLRET or ONLCR flag, but to leave the flag off otherwise (as in that case, you are writing to a pipe)

Comment: or use `getchar()` instead of `getch()`